# What is Important Files Folder Project in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans-7

I see some of my projects have '**Important Files**' folder under Projects window in NetBeans. Not all projects have this. That is not a physical folder on disk either and have listing of already existing files under 'Source Files' folder. What is that and how NetBeans populates this list of files? I am using NetBeans version 7.2

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Vipin:

The "nbproject" is the most important folder. If you delete this folder, and after that, you start a new project in netbeans, it's like beginning your project from zero.

Comment: I think this is not an answer to the question. This answer does not speak about the "import file" folder on netbeans, in the netbeans windows, but speaks about the projects configuration's files.

Comment: While this answer is correct in that `nbproject` is a very important folder for a NetBeans project, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: How is this the correct answer @Vipin? The answer below is more relevant!

Answer (score 3):

Plugins that extend PHP projects, be them stock or third-party, have the ability to define specific files or directories that are important to the project and developers may need quick access to.

This is demonstrated by [an official tutorial made specifically to explain how to extend a project type to add the "Important Files" node to the logical project view](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectextension.html).

> New NetBeans IDE APIs since NetBeans IDE 6.0 enable you to add new nodes to an existing project type's logical view, new objects to an existing project type's lookup, and new panels to an existing project type's Project Properties dialog box. For example, in this tutorial, to illustrate these extensions, we extend the web application project type's logical view, by adding a new "Important Files" node, exposing the content of the project's "nbproject" folder...

I can't say exactly why some of your projects have or do not have this "Important Files" node present, but I do know in the case of one of my own projects that Netbeans's native support for the PHP package manager "Composer" will show the Important Files with `composer.json` if it finds that file in the project folder.